# DLNA server with playback progress control

Tags: vlc, dlna, upnp, minidlna

I'm relatively new to using Linux on desktop and there are just a few things that I miss from Windows. One of them is Samsung AllShare. This is a DLNA server wich provides "play to", progress bar and volume control from PC to TV. My TV is not a smart one but it has DLNA client. Due to that it also doesn't have a progress bar when playing and the jump forward button forwards in 5 seconds steps, so when I must tune to the half of a movie, my fingers are numbing.
I already tried with MiniDLNA, VLC and Serviio as DLNA servers but they also doesn't provide a faster progress control feature.

So my question is: is there anyone of you who knows a DLNA/UPNP server with features described above or any way to control playback progress from server to client?

Answer (score 1):

**Xbmc/Kodi** amongs many other features also provides a DLNA server to stream its content to a DLNA client.

For sound only but not video there is an extremely light-weight DLNA server that can stream the output of **any** media player on your Ubuntu desktop though creating a selectable sound output device: [**pulseaudio-dlna**](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna):

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need a control point.
I can suggest:

- http://www.eezupnp.de/ - simple and clear. Can send files (video,music,images) both from PC and from media server. Nice
- http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/upplay/ - simple
- also gupnp-tools - includes a simple control point